# Vim's '(insert) VISUAL' mode?

Tags: vim, insert

The "`(insert) VISUAL`" mode can be entered by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> , <kbd>v</kbd> starting from insert mode.  This enters visual mode, but is displayed as "`(insert) VISUAL`" from within vim, and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> from this mode brings you back to insert mode, not normal mode.  The "`(insert) VISUAL`" mode is also entered by shifted arrowed keys from insert mode.

Two related questions:

1. There does not seem to be much documentation on this special mode.  Is there an easy way to search for information about it?  (edit: I'm aware of what <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> normally does.  The interaction with visual mode seems to be special.  The first paragraph was the easiest way to refer to what this mode is in the first place, as I don't know of a searchable name for it.)
2. How do you write `vmap` mappings reliably?  Namely, is there a consistent way to leave visual mode and end up in, say normal mode?  Or consistently end up in insert mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the second question: you can switch to normal mode from any other using `<C-\><C-n>`. There are no commands for reliably switching to visual or insert modes this way, but if you need only always switching to normal mode after visual it is sufficient. Note that most of the visual-mode mappings are working in `i<C-o>v` special mode without modifications.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up the second question.  I have a related question about how maps work in `i<C-o>v` here (which is what prompted this one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221213/why-does-this-vim-mapping-behave-differently-depending-on-how-visual-mode-was-en

Answer (score 14):

In *insert* mode, `<C-o>` allows you to execute *normal* mode commands without leaving *insert* mode. Vim tries to indicate the new state with `(insert)`. Since you are now temporally in *normal* mode, hitting `v` puts you in *visual* mode and Vim tries, again, to indicate the new state with `(insert) VISUAL`. Vim is in this state only because of the sequence of commands *you* performed and, as pointed out by others, that behavior is documented. At this point, it is normal and expected that `<Esc>` puts you back in *insert* mode since that's your original mode.

Someone with a deeper Vim understanding than me may be able to tell you if there's a reliable way to end up in `normal` from `insert` -> `(normal)` -> `visual` but I'd say that the whole idea sounds fishy to me.

Proper usage is:

1. do stuff in *normal* mode
2. enter *insert* mode to "insert" something
3. exit *insert* mode to go back to *normal* mode
4. do more stuff in *normal* mode
5. enter *visual* mode
6. do stuff in *visual* mode
7. exit *visual* mode to go back to *normal* mode
8. etc.

Basically, you are not supposed to be further than one `<Esc>` away from *normal* mode.

I can't imagine a scenario where using `v` after `<C-o>` makes any sense.

The best and preferred way to use Vim is to stay out of *insert* mode as much as possible. Using `<C-o>` to avoid leaving *insert* mode is a very poor strategy. I have no idea if that's what you do but, if you do it, you should reconsider that approach as soon as possible.

But I suspect you are trying to do something else which you, somehow, didn't think we needed to know.

Comment: The "`(insert) VISUAL`" mode is also entered by shifted arrowed keys from insert mode.  This is how I commonly encounter it.  The question was indeed prompted by "something else": I was debugging vim mappings that behaved completely different if it was activated from `VISUAL` vs `(insert) VISUAL`.  Further testing reveals though Vim usually goes out of its way so it doesn't matter, e.g. the vmap `vnoremap x <Esc>jjj` works as expected from `(insert) VISUAL` too.

Comment: One situation where `Ctrl+O, v` helps is when visual mode is used in a way to make edits. for example I have visual mode binds that call plugins which perform wrapping operations, e.g. from normal mode, `viw)` will wrap the current word inside parentheses, and `ve)` will wrap from the current cursor position to the end of the word in parentheses. What is not ideal is when I switch back to normal mode from insert mode it moves the cursor back one place and then I have to type (from insert mode) `<Esc>lve)` but here we can do `<C-O>ve)` and it can be shortened further with an insert mode bind.

Comment: Old post but thought I would add that I agree with @StevenLu and I think it's a bit much to say using temporary modes is *always* a "very poor strategy". For example if I'm in insert mode and want to skip over a word but continue typing it is much more convenient to do `<C-o>w` than having to exit to normal first: `<Esc>wi`. You may even have to do `2w` if the cursor is moved back.

Comment: It's a good thing I didn't use the word "*always*" in my answer, then. FWIW, the use case you mention is just a matter of `<S-Right>` or `<C-Right>` depending on your system. No need to resort to convoluted combos.

Answer (score 2):

It's documented at `:h Operator-pending` and just below that at `:h mode-switching`. Mappings for visual mode will also work for (insert) visual mode. See `:h map-modes` for a review of mode mapping. `vmap` will map for both visual and select modes, `xmap` will map for only visual but not select, and `smap` will map for only select but not visual. In general, you should use the `noremap` versions of these mapping commands to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: You have a mistake here: `v[nore]map` (and `[nore]map`) are defining mappings for both select and visual modes (+ normal and operator-pending for `noremap`), `x[nore]map` is used for visual mode only, `s[nore]map` is used for select mode.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in insert mode executes one command and then exits back to insert mode. See [`:h i_CTRL-O`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O).

For the second question.

I do not think you there is a reliable way to exit into one mode or another. The most reliable way I think is to start in the mode you want to end in.