# Why does this Vim mapping behave differently depending on how Visual mode was entered?

Tags: vim, insert, keymapping

This question is what prompted a previous question of mine here:  [Vim's '(insert) VISUAL' mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203524/vims-insert-visual-mode)

In that question I asked about "`VISUAL`" mode vs "`(insert) VISUAL`" mode, which is where you enter visual mode directly from insert mode.  I have found a mapping that behaves differently depending on the "subtype" of visual mode, and I don't understand why:

```
vnoremap x <Esc>jjj
vnoremap <A-[> <C-G>ugv
```

The first mapping illustrates how Vim goes out of its way to make mappings to behave consistently:  pressing <kbd>x</kbd> from "`VISUAL`" mode and pressing <kbd>x</kbd> from "`(insert) VISUAL`" mode will both move the cursor down 3 lines.  The latter does not exit to insert mode and enter three `j`'s.   So `<Esc>` is not behaving differently depending on the mode, even though outside of a mapping it would behave differently from these two modes.

The second mapping illustrates how some maps behave inconsistently.  If you highlight a word and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> then the word is replaced with `ugv` if done from "`VISUAL`" mode but nothing happens if done from "`(insert) VISUAL`" mode.  Presumably this is because Vim is executing the normal mode commands `ugv` for 'undo' and 'reselect-visual'.

This is a strange inconsistency.  It is a minimal example I ran into when debugging my mappings, and would like to know why it works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your examples and I think your analysis is right.

When I **type** `<C-G>ugv` from *(insert) visual* mode, I get the expected results: `<C-G>` switches to *(insert) select* mode, `ugv` replaces the selection with those characters. A mapping should behave in the same way.

I guess this is a bug; the entire *(insert)* submode is quite special, not frequently used, and therefore prone to bugs. You could delve into the source code yourself, or raise this issue on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php). Due to the obscurity of the issue, it may be hard to garner much interest from the devs, though.